# How can JenkinsPipelineUnit be used with shared declarative pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is my test (copied from the snippets in the docs)

```
package vars

import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import com.lesfurets.jenkins.unit.declarative.*

class ExampleDeclarativePipelineTest extends DeclarativePipelineTest {
  // Setup environment for running unit tests
  @Override
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
  }

  @Test
  public void should_execute_without_errors() throws Exception {
      //def script = runScript("vars/exampleDeclarativePipeline.groovy")
      def script = runScript("vars/Jenkinsfile")
      assertJobStatusSuccess()
      printCallStack()
  }
}
```

That works if I have an actual Jenkinsfile, but I defined my pipeline in my shared library (common pattern at this point) and it looks like this:

```
def call(Map config) {
    pipeline {
        agent none
        stages {
            stage('Example Build') {
                agent { docker 'maven:3-alpine' }
                steps {
                    echo 'Hello, Maven'
                    sh 'mvn --version'
                }
            }
            stage('Example Test') {
                agent { docker 'openjdk:8-jre' }
                steps {
                    echo 'Hello, JDK'
                    echo 'Hello, JDK'
                    echo 'Hello, JDK'
                    echo 'Hello, JDK'
                    echo 'Hello, JDK'
                    sh 'java -version'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I point my test to this Groovy script (`def script = runScript("vars/exampleDeclarativePipeline.groovy")`) it seems to do nothing. It executes but I don't get a stack trace or anything (if it's a standard Jenkinsfile it works).

How can I test my shared pipeline code?

Wasn't sure if this was a bug so I opened one: https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/issues/380

Comment: I fixed this somehow but cannot remember- I closed the github issue I linked to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same issue/roadblock; the 'solution' I used is to create a Jenkinsfile (per var in vars) and include my library as a '*Shared Library*' via [helper.registerSharedLibrary()](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit#testing-shared-libraries) (*ProjectSource*). Example-code based on my workaround:

File structure:

```
project_root
├── test
|    ├── vars
|    |    └── test-jenkinsfile.groovy
|    └── TestSpec.groovy
├── vars
|    └── test.groovy
...
```

test.groovy:

```
def call(stuff) {
    pipelines {
        agent none
        stages('hello') {
            stage {
                echo 'world'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TestSpec.groovy:

```
...
class TestSpec extends DeclarativePipelineTest {
    @Override
    @Before
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Set dir info
        baseScriptRoot = ''
        scriptRoots = ['test/vars/']
        scriptExtension = 'groovy'
        
        
        super.setUp()

        // load own shared library
        def library = LibraryConfiguration.library().name('hello-world')
                        .defaultVersion('<notNeeded>')
                        .allowOverride(true)
                        .implicit(true)
                        .targetPath('<notNeeded>')
                        .retriever(ProjectSource.projectSource())
                        .build()
        helper.registerSharedLibrary(library)

        ...
    }

    @Test
    void runHelloWorldPipeline() {
        runScript('test-jenkinsfile.groovy')
        printCallStack()
        assertJobStatusSuccess()
    }
}
```

test-jenkinsfile.groovy:

```
...
@Library('hello-world')  _
test {}
```

**Warning**: I just started (8h ago) down this route and it seems to be working, for me and for now.

Comment: It still works fine here; I would like to add that if you need mocking, you might want to set `helper.libLoader.preloadLibraryClasses = false` inside your setUp(). (I use `mockito-inline` for mocking (static) functions/classes.

Comment: Still working fine here; even after multiple updates and upgrades